# Very peculiar - submit once the first time, twice the 2nd time, trice the 3rd time .. and so on .. what I did wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

Working with a modal form that submits edited information via ajax post. The thing is, it submitted once the first time .. fire up the modal form again, then submit, and twice it goes and so on and so forth. Does anyone had this sort of experience before? Please help.

```
$("#editInfo").click(function () {
    valform = ["realname","email"];
    valneed = 2;
    $('#smallModal .modal-body').empty();
    $('#smallModal .modal-body').load('/profile.php?action=profile_edit_info');
    $('#smallModal .modal-title').text('Edit Personal Information');
    $('#smallModal').modal('show')

    $('#smallModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#smallModal #profileeditinfoform").keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13 && event.target.nodeName!='TEXTAREA')
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });

        $("#realname_comment").hide();
        $("#email_comment").hide();

        $('#realname').bind("change", function() {
            $('#realname').addClass("spinner");
            var v_realname = verifyVar($('#realname').val(),'name');
            displayVerify(v_realname,'realname');
        });

        $('#email').bind("change", function() {
            $('#email').addClass("spinner");
            var v_email = verifyVar($('#email').val(),'email');
            displayVerify(v_email,'email');
        });

        $("#editinfo_submit_btn").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#loader').fadeIn();

            formData = $("#profileeditinfoform").serialize();
            var v_submit = submitEditInfo(formData);
            verifySubmitEditInfo(v_submit);

            $('#loader').fadeOut();
        });
    });
});

function submitEditInfo(data) {
    var alldata = data + '&action=profileeditinfo';
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: alldata,
        url: '/ajax/submit.php'
    });
}

function verifySubmitEditInfo(ajaxCall) {
        ajaxCall.success(function(realData) {
                response = JSON.parse(realData)
                if (!response.success) {
                    $.gritter.add({
                        title: response.title,
                        image: '/img/custom/fail.png',
                        sticky: false,
                        text: response.message
                    });
                } else {
                    valform = [];
                    $("#submitdiv").hide();
                    $("#profileeditinfoform").find("input:text").val('');
                    $('#infodiv').slideUp(200).load('/divloader.php?req=profile_info').slideDown(200);
                    $.gritter.add({
                        title: response.title,
                        image: '/img/custom/success.png',
                        sticky: false,
                        text: response.message
                    });
                    $("#smallModal").modal('hide');
                }
        });
}
```

Comment: This means you have multiple instances of the modal. Check your DOM

Comment: Sandeep, I don't really get what you mean by DOM. Does it mean I have multiple variable by the same name?

Comment: Check in your developer console, if you see multiple Modal's

Comment: Sometimes this happens when you bound in incorrect position. So every time, you run through all code, binding. Next time, it has two of same bound functions. Next time three.

Comment: When you call `.on()` or `.bind()` or `.click()` or any other event handler setup function, that **adds** an event handler without removing any previous event handlers. For that reason, common advice is that adding event handlers from inside *other* event handlers is almost always a bad idea and indicative of a fundamental problem.

Comment: Casey and Pointy .. I think I'm getting it .. gotta go through the codes again now ... thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you click, you're adding a new event handler:

```
$('#smallModal').on('shown.bs.modal' //...
```

Are you sure you want to do this on "click", or might it be better to set this up outside of the click handler?

In fact, you're binding event handlers as a response to other events all over this code. That's probably not a great idea, unless you unbind them once you're done.

Comment: ahh .. I think I get what you mean .. lemme try to have that fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull out your binders, you bind a new time every time the button  is clicked! Only bind on load, not under button click event.