# Why ng-click is getting called the number of times button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, dialog

I am developing an angular-node.js application where I have a button which when clicked triggers a post request. I am facing a strange issue where this post request is getting called the number of times the button is clicked. For example if I click button for first time - post request is called once, if I click again that is the second time post request executes twice and so on. I am clueless what is wrong with the code , here is the code I have :

angular.js:

```
$scope.addActivity = function(actor){

    AJS.dialog2("#impact-dialog").show();

    $(".dialog-close-button-impact").click(function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        AJS.dialog2("#impact-dialog").hide();
    });

    var countClicks = 0;
    $(".SubmitImpact").click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();


        alert("I am being called again and again");
        countClicks++;
        alert(countClicks);
        AJS.dialog2("#impact-dialog").hide();

        var data = {
            productName: $scope.productName,
            actor: actor,
            activity : $('#activity').val(),
            checked: false
        };

        console.log("Input data for add impact" + actor)

        $http.post('/addActivity', data)
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.activities = [];

                for (var activity in data) {

                    $scope.activities.push({
                        text: data[activity].activity,
                        id: data[activity].actor,
                        checked: data[activity].checked
                    });
                }
                actor = "";


            }).error(function(data){
                console.log('Error in adding activity' + data)
            });

    });

};
```

node.js code:

```
app.post('/addActivity',function(req, res) {

    console.log("I am going to add activity");

    console.log("Checked value:" +req.body.checked)

    impactMapActivity.create(
        {productName: req.body.productName,
            checked: req.body.checked,
            actor: req.body.actor,
            activity: req.body.activity

        }, function(err,data){
            if (err)
            //{
                res.send(err);
            console.log(err);

            impactMapActivity.find({
                productName : req.body.productName
            }, function(err, data) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                console.log("Printing Data" + data)
                res.json(data);
            });
        }
    );

});
```

template code:

```
<span><button class=" aui-button dialog-show-button-impact div.actor-\{{$index}}"  style="float: left" title="$i18n.getText('add.activity')"
                                                                            ng-click="addActivity(actor.id)"><span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-add">Add</span>
                                                            </button>\{{actor.id}}</span>
```

updated code after removing jquery as suggested :

```
$scope.addActivity = function(actor){

        AP.require('dialog', function(dialog){
            dialog.create({
                key: 'activity-content',
                width: '40%',
                height: '30%',
                chrome: true,

            });
        });

        AP.require('events', function(events){
            events.on('customEvent', function(){
                console.log(arguments[0]);
                var data = {
                    productName: $scope.productName,
                    actor: actor,
                    activity : arguments[0],
                    checked: false
                };

                $http.post('/addActivity', data)
                    .success(function(data){
                        $scope.data = data;
                        $scope.activities = [];

                        for (var activity in data) {

                            $scope.activities.push({
                                text: data[activity].activity,
                                id: data[activity].actor,
                                checked: data[activity].checked
                            });
                        }

                        actor = "";

                        AP.require("messages", function(messages){
                            //create a message
                            var message = messages.success('','Activity added');
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                messages.clear(message);
                            }, 2000);
                        });


                    }).error(function(data){

                        AP.require("messages", function(messages){
                            //create a message
                            var message = messages.error('','Error in Adding Activity');
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                messages.clear(message);
                            }, 2000);
                        });
                    });
            });
        });

    };
```

But I still face the same problem.

Comment: Your angular code is quite confused. As a general rule, you should not be mixing jQuery with Angular. Either one or the other. All of the things you are using $ for should be using the Angular varients.

Comment: Yeah I know that but right now I am not in a position to refactor it . I just need to fix this issue. Anyhow let me try to explain you the angular part. It addActivity calls a dialog box to open , (.submitImpact ) is the code to submit the dialog form. I hope it helped.

Comment: If you just want to hack it to work, set a var inProgress = true before the post, wrap the post in a if(!inProgress) and set inProgress = false in the success/error callback of the post.

Comment: No that is not working.

Comment: I have similar problem but there is no concrete suggestion provided. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131714/very-peculiar-submit-once-the-first-time-twice-the-2nd-time-trice-the-3rd-ti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `addActivity` function is calling a `.click` handler every time it is called. Hence, on the second click, there are two `.click` handlers attached to the element.

There are several ways of fixing this:

- Refactoring the code in Angular and using `ng-click` (not possible)
- Adding the click handler only once. This would involve moving the click handler outside the `addActivity` function. (best way)
- Using [`jQuery.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (as suggested by Sampath).
- Using [name-spaced jQuery events](https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/).

---

After refactoring, the code should look like this:

```
AP.require('events', function(events){
    // ...
});


$scope.addActivity = function(actor){
  AP.require('dialog', function(dialog){
      // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @musically_ut can you please elaborate the second approach.

Comment: I changed the entire code and removed jquery (updated the code)

Comment: But I still face the same problem. I have updated my question please have a look

Comment: so how am I supposed to handle this now as I removed jquery. please check the updated code in the question.

Comment: @user_dev have added what the code should look like.

Comment: Changing from events.on to event.once made it to work. Though the concept is same what you explained earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Please try as shown below.

```
$(".SubmitImpact").one("click", function () {

    //alert("This will be clicked only once.");

});
```

[**.one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: That worked, but can you please tell me why this is happening at all as I have other similar buttons that works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry,exactly I don't know why this is happening here and there.But if you use proper DOM element handling techniques like above then you can avoid such issues.